# will I get garageband back if I factory reset my ipad AIR 2

Tags: ipad, software-update, garageband

as I recall, my old ipad air 2 came with Garageband. I made the mistake of leaving automatic app updates on and now, since it cannot update to ios 16, it cannot open Garageband either (since it is only compatible with ios16 and has already decided to update that app).

I'd really like to keep using my Garageband. If I factory reset my ipad, will it be for nought, or will my old, usable Garageband be back?

Comment: It shouldn't have let you update to an incompatible version. If you delete it & reinstall, or try to install to any iDevice which is not compatible with the latest version, it should allow you to download an earlier version. https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVivH.jpg

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for your response! sadly it does not allow this on my ipad, it still requests ios16, even if I deleted the app and its associated data. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the same AppleID as you used to originally 'purchase' it? [Purchase applies whether or not you had to pay money for it]. You cannot now 'purchase' an older version, you need to already own it in your purchase history - then it will offer the old version.

Comment: @Tetsujin YES it worked! I signed into my first apple ID and it worked! thank you very much <3